# Cannot load image

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Why can't internet explorer 11 display this image?

https://www.brainyoo.de/Brainyoo2Web/javax.faces.resource/logo.gif.xhtml?ln=img

other urls work:
https://www.brainyoo.de/Brainyoo2Web/javax.faces.resource/icon_gross-neue-Karte-erstellen.png.xhtml?ln=img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had this in our apache config

```
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

which didnt allow ie to detect the mimetype.